# Converting rows to columns using UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

Following is my sample dataset:

```
ID  Prod1   Prod2   Prod3
1   ABC01   CDE02   XYZ03
```

I want to convert rows to columns and my desired output is:

```
ID   Products
1    ABC01  
1    CDE02  
1    XYZ03
```

I tried using UNPIVOT, but my code didn't work:

```
Select Id, Products
From Sample
UNPIVOT
(
    Products
    FOR Id IN ([1],[2],[3])
) AS P
```

Can someone please help me converting these rows to columns for each ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a `VALUES` clause to unpivot the data:

```
SELECT S.ID,
       V.Product
FROM dbo.Sample S
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(S.Prod1),(S.Prod2),(S.Prod3))V(Product);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2127fcf53458bb773c41667ac96e7385)

Comment: OP is actually looking for PIVOT.  The question is phrased backwards

Comment: That's not what their question says, @JohnCappelletti *"Following is my sample dataset: {de-normalised data} I want to convert rows to columns and my desired output is: {Normalised data}"*

Comment: Yup I know.  His comment to me was is data set was ID and Product and he wants to "flip them"

Comment: Undelete your answer then @JohnCappelletti , as it's clearly correct too. I *think* the OP may have been commenting on that the datatet returned the column "item" too. At a guess.