# Convert Rows to Columns and Forward Fill First Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which has a unique URL in the first column, followed by a random number of unique keywords. I would like to transpose the keywords into a single row and forward fill the url as per my desired output below.

```
0                              1          2          3          4          5      
www.example.com/page1         car        dog        cat        bat        apple
www.example.com/page2         dog        car 
www.example.com/page3         cat        bat        apple
```

Desired Output:

```
0                              1          2          3          4          5   
www.example.com/page1         car       
www.example.com/page1         dog
www.example.com/page1         cat
www.example.com/page1         bat
www.example.com/page1         apple
www.example.com/page2         dog
www.example.com/page2         car
www.example.com/page3         cat
www.example.com/page3         bat
www.example.com/page3         apple
```

what I've tried:
I've looked at these solutiosn, but neither seem to work for me. I've also consulted the docs on pd.melt but could not get it to work. (Still learning. Any help appreciated).
[Pandas create new date rows and forward fill column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526973/pandas-create-new-date-rows-and-forward-fill-column-values)
[Converting rows to columns using UNPIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222022/converting-rows-to-columns-using-unpivot)

Comment: Why keep the other columns if they are no longer used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it with `melt` is pretty straight forward.

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='0', value_vars=df.columns[1:], value_name='1').drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values('0')
```

This only works properly if your empty cells are shown as `NaN` in your DataFrame. From the example you posted, it looks like they are actually not `NaN` values but rather empty strings `''`. In that case you first need to replace them with: `df.replace('',np.NaN, inplace=True)`. Otherwise you will get rows with empty entries in column 1.

Im also not sure why you want to keep the empty columns 1 to 5 because if you need to fill them later, you can just create them, it's the same procedure as if you tried to fill / override an existing empty column. But for the sake of it, you can add the empty columns back in:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=list('2345'))]).fillna('')
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't need to keep the columns - just thought it might emphasis what I needed the final output to be, but looks like it just added confusion! Your answer is perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the empty columns after but you can always re-add them

I got the output by stacking and merging with the original df

`df.drop([0], axis=1).stack().droplevel(1).to_frame(name=1).merge(df[[0]], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')`

Final add the other columns
`df[[2,3,4,5]] = ''`

```
       1                      0 2 3 4 5
0    car  www.example.com/page1
0    dog  www.example.com/page1
0    cat  www.example.com/page1
0    bat  www.example.com/page1
0  apple  www.example.com/page1
1    dog  www.example.com/page2
1    car  www.example.com/page2
2    cat  www.example.com/page3
2    bat  www.example.com/page3
2  apple  www.example.com/page3
```

Comment: Good point about the other columns, I actually don't need them. I thought it might make the example clearer!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.   Setup first:

```
df_orig = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'0': {0: 'www.example.com/page1',
  1: 'www.example.com/page2',
  2: 'www.example.com/page3'},
 '1': {0: 'car', 1: 'dog', 2: 'cat'},
 '2': {0: 'dog', 1: 'car', 2: 'bat'},
 '3': {0: 'cat', 1: None, 2: 'apple'},
 '4': {0: 'bat', 1: None, 2: None},
 '5': {0: 'apple', 1: None, 2: None}}
)

# first way, df.melt:
df = df_orig.melt(id_vars="0", value_vars=list("12345"), value_name="1")
df_melt = df.drop(columns="variable").dropna().sort_values("0", ignore_index=True)

# second way, df.unstack:
df_unstack = df_orig.set_index("0", drop=True).unstack().dropna().reset_index(0, drop=True).to_frame()
```

output:

```
                       0      1
0  www.example.com/page1    car
1  www.example.com/page1    dog
2  www.example.com/page1    cat
3  www.example.com/page1    bat
4  www.example.com/page1  apple
5  www.example.com/page2    dog
6  www.example.com/page2    car
7  www.example.com/page3    cat
8  www.example.com/page3    bat
9  www.example.com/page3  apple
```